# white screen on simulator iphone Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I watched this video on YouTube :
Xcode How to Create a Webview for iOS Applications

I followed video but if I run my app on simulator, only I see white screen.

[image]

This ViewController.h

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;

}


@end


//
```

//  ViewController.m
//

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.com"]; NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL]; myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES; [myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Can you get me fix this error?

Comment: Show the code. Do you have any `UIelement` on your VCs? Also share a screenshot of your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually load the request after you create it!

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yoururl.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```